# Unmatched column names/values when inserting data in Cassandra cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cql, cql3, cqlsh

So I am using the current query to insert data into my column family:

```
INSERT INTO airports (apid, name, iata, icao, x, y, elevation, code, name, oa_code, dst, cid, name, timezone, tz_id) VALUES (12012,'Ararat Airport','ARY','YARA','142.98899841308594','-37.30939865112305',1008,{ code: 'AS', name: 'Australia', oa_code: 'AU', dst: 'U',city: { cid: 1, name: '', timezone: '', tz_id: ''}});
```

Now, I'm getting the error: `Unmatched column names/values` when this is my current model for the airports columnfamily:

```
CREATE TYPE movielens.cityudt (
    cid varint,
    name text,
    timezone varint,
    tz_id text
);

CREATE TYPE movielens.countryudt (
    code text,
    name text,
    oa_code text,
    dst text,
    city frozen<cityudt>
);

CREATE TABLE movielens.airports (
    apid varint PRIMARY KEY,
    country frozen<countryudt>,
    elevation varint,
    iata text,
    icao text,
    name text,
    x varint,
    y varint
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

But I cant see the problem with the insert! Can someone help me figure out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I did manage to get this work after adjusting your `x` and `y` columns to `double`s:

```
INSERT INTO airports (apid, name, iata, icao, x, y, elevation, country)
VALUES (12012,'Ararat Airport','ARY','YARA',142.98899841308594,-37.30939865112305,
        1008,{ code: 'AS', name: 'Australia', oa_code: 'AU', dst: 'U', 
            city:{ cid: 1, name: '', timezone: 0, tz_id: ''}});

cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM airports WHERE apid=12012;

 apid  | country                                                                                                    | elevation | iata | icao | name           | x       | y
-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+------+------+----------------+---------+----------
 12012 | {code: 'AS', name: 'Australia', oa_code: 'AU', dst: 'U', city: {cid: 1, name: '', timezone: 0, tz_id: ''}} |      1008 |  ARY | YARA | Ararat Airport | 142.989 | -37.3094

(1 rows)
```

Remember that VARINTs don't take single quotes (like `timezone`).

Also, you were specifying each type's column, when you just needed to specify `country` in your column list (as you mentioned).

Comment: Hey Aaron thanks! But I'm not encountering this error when inserting: `D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.1\airports.cql:7181:InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid user type literal for country: field city is not of type frozen<cityudt>"` - Here is the gist for airports.cql: https://gist.github.com/ryankshah/636eb1eb5788514be1147c1dfd84bd7a

Comment: @madcrazydrumma So I was getting that when `timezone` was given a value of `''`.  When I changed that to `0` it works.

Comment: I changed the type of `timezone` to `text` and sorted that. However now I am getting the errors in the form: `D:\apache-cassandra-3.11.1\airports.cql:7179:InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid INTEGER constant (3012) for "y" of type text"`

Comment: Scrap that, I changed x and y to `double` and I'm still getting an error. This is because the csv i am reading in is output from a MySQL select/concat_ws statement to get values out of my relational table. However I am not sure how to fix this statement

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe change them to `TEXT`s just to get around type errors?

Comment: the errors are infact stemming from the format of the CSV file I use before I convert it to the query statements. For example one line might not have an ICAO varchar and therefore use the next value in place of this one which might be the wrong type. Thus, I need to fix the following SQL query: `SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',
 AP.apid, AP.name, AP.iata, AP.icao, AP.x, AP.y, AP.elevation,
 CO.code, CO.name, CO.oa_code, CO.dst,
 CI.cid, CI.name, CI.timezone, CI.tz_id
) FROM airports as AP, countries as CO, cities as CI
WHERE AP.city = CI.cid AND CI.country = CO.code;
`

Answer (score 0):

When inserting into a frozen udt, you do not have to specify the insert for all the rows (even those inside the frozen udt), therefore to fix the query I had to remove all those up to the `elevation` column and add `country`.